# Simple question about integration

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have differential equation

${dy} =\sqrt{-x}{dx} ,\: x< 0 $

My attempt

$
\int {dy} =-\int \sqrt{-x}{d(-x)}
\\
y=-\frac{2}{3}(\sqrt{-x})^{3}+C
$

Is it correct?

Comment: Check by differentiation of the solution you got. It seems ok to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

For the right-hand integral, you could also use the substitution $u=-x$, $u>0$ (though it is the same thing):

$$
\begin{align}
\int{\sqrt{-x}}\,dx &= -\int{\sqrt{u}}\,du \\
&= -\frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
&= -\frac{2}{3}(-x)^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
&= -\frac{2}{3}(\sqrt{-x})^{3} \\
\end{align}
$$

So the final equation you have is

$$
\begin{align}
\int {dy} &= \int \sqrt{-x}\,dx \\
y &= -\frac{2}{3}(\sqrt{-x})^{3} + \color{gray}{C} \\
\end{align}
$$

which leads you to your result.

Comment: what about $+C$?

Comment: I just meant to give you the pointer, but I'll add that in!

Comment: @Woland I accidentally edited your question, replacing it with my answer. Very silly of me! Please reject that edit.